# CSS Text Gradient For IE 11 and Other Browsers

Tags: css, linear-gradients

Following code for text-gradient is not working in IE11

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 56px;
    font-weight: 600;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #00a79d 0%, #8dc63f 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1>
    <span>The Leading Peer to Peer</span>
</h1>
```

How do support IE11 as well as other modern browsers?

Comment: not fully doable (not that i've found) in IE11 without the use of SVG or JS. these webkit attributes background-clip and text-fill are not very IE compatible.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,  rgba(66,229,150,1) 0%,rgba(60,179,185,1) 100%);
```

also change your hex value to RGB color.

Comment: no need to convert to rgba whatsoever. -webkit selectors are not really usable on IE anyway.

Comment: duplicate of :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729494/gradient-background-with-text-clip-for-ie11-and-safari